# Error when vagrant up(docker-compose plugin)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, vagrant

I want to make database environment with docker-compose plugin(vagrant).
But when I do `docker compose`, it occurs following error.

```
C:\db>vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'centos/7' version '1902.01' is up to date...
==> default: Machine already provisioned. Run `vagrant provision` or use the `--provision`
==> default: flag to force provisioning. Provisioners marked to run always will still run.
==> default: Running provisioner: docker_compose...
    default: Checking for Docker Compose installation...
    default: Symlinking Docker Compose 1.22.0 in guest machine...
    default: Running docker-compose up...
==> default: bash: line 4: 18581 Segmentation fault      /usr/local/bin/docker-compose-1.22.0 -f "/vagrant/docker-compose.yml" up -d
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

 /usr/local/bin/docker-compose-1.22.0  -f "/vagrant/docker-compose.yml" up -d

Stdout from the command:



Stderr from the command:

bash: line 4: 18581 Segmentation fault      /usr/local/bin/docker-compose-1.22.0 -f "/vagrant/docker-compose.yml" up -d
```